# How to tell if an Android device will be able to provide a location?

Tags: android

I'm writing a geo app and it all works nicely, but I'm considering how it'll work on devices that don't have GPS or 3G, and the wifi may be off or not provide location info.

Is my best bet to just request a location update (or use the last known) and assume there is a way to get the location (whether GPS or network) or does the framework include a way to see what's available, and avoid the geo-lookup delay?

I figure on a device with no GPS my app should provide a UI for the user to specify the location, AND remember it in the sharedprefs so they don't have to keep re-entering it (I'm thinking devices like Google TV, and tablets).

I'd appreciate suggestions on how to handle the process of acquiring location in the context of various devices that have different levels of geo-awareness, and how to handle that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke `LocationManager.getAllProviders()` to retrieve all location providers, or invoke `LocationManager.getProviders(true)` to retrieve active location providers.

```
boolean hasActiveLocationProvider = false;
LocationManager locationManager = Context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
for (String providerName:providers) {
  if (providerName.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) 
      || providerName.equals(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
    hasActiveLocationProvider = true;
  }
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html

Comment: It appears that this only tells me what theoretical providers there are, not what's actually available now. e.g. if I run the above code on a device with GPS and all network switched off, it still returns two items, GPS and NETWORK. I need more detail than that, I need to know which are available, or at least switched on, is there an API to do that?

Comment: I extended your example above (thank you) so the NETWORK location provider is also checked for connectivity, even if it's available..... ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)application.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); boolean isConnected = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo()==null || !(cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting()

Answer (score 0):

Extending aleung's and Ollie's answer this is what worked best for me. There may be a few more gaps to fill.

```
private boolean hasActiveLocationProvider(Context context) {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
    for (String providerName : providers) {
        if (providerName.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (providerName.equals(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            boolean isConnected = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
            if (isConnected) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```